# Problems after upgrading to 12.04 - black screen after log in!

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I just upgraded my stationary Dell to 12.04 but ran into problems. After restart I can log in but after that all I have is a black screen - nothing! No terminal to type any commands in... What shall I do?

Comment: When did it happen, immediately after reboot or after installing the video drivers? Can you go to a terminal session (ALT+FN

Comment: It happened directly after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of VGA drivers you got ?

from the grub menu at start up choose recovery mode and from that choose failsafeX mode from there install the VGA drivers .